# How to do an if statement for URL resolve to a certain IP address?

Tags: java, ip, host, inet

If I use an URL www.stackoverflow.com then it'll resolve to an IP address of 31.13.72.49.

This is no problem, I know how to do that with a simple code:

```
    InetAddress add = InetAddress.getByName("www.stackoverflow.com");
    return add.getHostAddress();
```

But I want to do it in a if statement for my list of blocked IP addresses (love stackoverflow btw :) Just an example).

E.g. My blocked list contains ("31.13.72.49", "www.y.com", "198.0.10.2")

If I entered www.stackoverflow.com then it'll acknowledge it is an bad IP address (by knowing the resolved IP for it is 31.13.72.49), and prints an error message (saying perhaps, website is banned from using) afterwards. Vice versa if I entered URL with only IP address in the blocked list.

I'm not sure what to do. I know the equals keyword or == to match but since they're not the same (although resolves to each other), I don't know how to proof they're indeed from the same family.

PS: I'm doing this in Java eclipse (import java.net.InetAddress;).

Answer (score 1):

Use the equals method of the InetAddress class

Comment: Get the inetaddress for both of them. Then inetAddress.equals(inetAddress2)